# Swift Change Xib Height Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

I implemented 2 Xib file to View Controller (1 View , 1 CollectionView). I want to show/hide the view when scrolling. I can hide view (set height:0) , but when I want to get back (set height:50) , it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y < 0{

        self.searchFieldView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        self.searchFieldView.clipsToBounds = true
        //self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    else{

        self.searchFieldView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        //self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't keep stacking constraints to a view. You need to remove the old one before applying new one.

Comment: if you mean _not visible_ by _"not working"_, then try to update the scrollview's content size as well – if not, specify what _"not working"_ means, please.

Comment: I cannot apply new one because this topView (SearchField) keep some data. @Desdenova. I just want to hide as NavigationController when scrolling.

Comment: @holex I think its not about scrollview size becuase it has top contraint to topview

Comment: @codeByThey I have no idea what is `topView` or what does it do. My point was, in your if clause you are applying two different constraint to same anchor. You can't do that unless you deactivate or remove the old one. And in your case, you don't even need that. Just change the constant of the constraint.

Comment: Top View is self.searchFieldView. I just change the height constraint but not working

Comment: @codeByThey, do you _think_ or did you _try_?

Comment: I think because I know it is not about this question

Answer (score 1):

Take reference of height of the searchFieldView from xib and change its constant value based on condition.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vwHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y < 0{

        vwHeightConstraint.constant = 0

        self.searchFieldView.clipsToBounds = true
        //self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }else{
         vwHeightConstraint.constant = 50

        //self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Hope it will work.once try this one